# Cannon sliding an inclined plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A classical question but seems I get is wrong. A cannon is sliding an inclined plane. As some point (where we cannon speed is $v_0$ downwards) it shoots a missile horizontally with speed $v$. What should be the speed $v$ to stop the cannon completely? Assume the cannon has mass $M$ and missile $m$.

My preliminary solution is that we write out the momentum conservation as

$$
(M+m)\boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}_0 =  m \boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}} + M \boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}_0 '
$$

where last term is zero since cannon stops. However, now I have a problem that vectors $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}_0$ and $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{v}}$ should be colinear, but they clearly can't. Many thanks for tips and/or solution.

Comment: If there aren't colinear, why don't you decompose $\mathbf{v}$ onto $\hat{\mathbf{v_0}}$ and a normal vector? Then solve the momentum conservation for the tangencial component.

Comment: Is "downwards" vertically down, or just parallel to the incline? Consider same for "horizontal." Looks like you consider horizontal to be parallel to incline. Thus downwards and horizontal are both parallel to incline?

Comment: @jpf, by downwards I meant parallel to inclined plane.

Answer (score 0):

since the cannon comes to a complete stop, it must transfer all its momentum to the projectile, and so the component of the projectiles finle momentum parralel to the cannons initial momentum.
$$
m_c\times u_c=m_p\times v_p \times \cos(\theta)
$$
Which you can rearange to get:
$$
v_p=\frac{m_c\times u_c}{m_p\times \cos(\theta)}
$$
The component of the projectiles motion perpendicular to the momentum of the cannon would be transfered to the slope.

$m_c$ is the mass of the cannon 
$m_p$ is the mass of the projectile 
$v_c$ is the velocity of the cannon 
$v_p$ is the velocity of the projectile 
$\theta$ is the incline of the plane

Comment: What are the symbols definitions in your post?